# Reactjs: How to recognized clicked list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, redux

I'm having trouble with my list of buttons. What I'm trying to achieve is simple: click button a, show list of a1 to a3, click button b, show list of b1 to b3. I'm trying to make react to recognize which button is clicked. So far i ended up with nothing, everytime i click a button button a and b will display its children

these are my codes

**CategoryContainer**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

import {getCategory} from '../actions/categoryActions'
import {ShowSubCategory} from '../actions/interactionActions'
import {ShowItemCategory} from '../actions/interactionActions'

import Category from '../components/category'

class CategoryContainer extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log('category props', this.props.categories);

    this.state = {
      showsubcategory: false,
      showitemcategory: false,
      selectedsubcat: null,
      selecteditemcat: null
    }
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    console.log('masuk CDM');
    this.props.fetchCategory()
  }

  toggleSubCategory = (event) => {
    console.log('masuk togglesubcategory', event);
    this.setState({showsubcategory: !this.state.showsubcategory}, ()=>{
      var isOpen = this.state.showsubcategory
      this.props.showSubCategory(isOpen)
      // if(isOpen){
      //   console.log('masuk block');
      //   document.getElementById("subcategorycontainer-" + id).style.display = "block"
      //this does not work
      // }
      // else{
      //   console.log('masuk none');
      //   document.getElementById("subcategorycontainer-" + id).style.display = "none"
      // }
    })
  }

  render(){
    var viewtypequery = window.innerWidth >= 1025 ? "computers" : "mobile"
    return(
      <Category alphabets={this.state.alph}
        categorylist={this.props.categories}
        view={viewtypequery}
        isFetching={this.props.fetching}
        togglesub={this.toggleSubCategory}
        showsub={this.state.showsubcategory}
      />
    )
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('state mapstate', state);
  return{
    categories: state.category.categories,
    fetching: state.category.isfetching,
    error: state.category.error,
    showsubcategory: state.interaction.showsubcategory,
    showitemcategory: state.interaction.showitemcategory
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
      fetchCategory: () => {
        dispatch(getCategory())
      },
      showSubCategory: (showsubcategory) => {
        dispatch(ShowSubCategory(showsubcategory))
      },
      showItemCategory: (showitemcategory) => {
        dispatch(ShowItemCategory(showitemcategory))
      }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CategoryContainer)
```

**category**

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router'

import Subcategory from './subcategory'

import BrandContainer from '../containers/brandContainer'


class Category extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props)
}

  render(){
    console.log('isi ref cuk', this.subcatcontainer);
    console.log('props category', this.props);
    console.log('from category', this.props.categorylist);
    if(this.props.fetching)
      return(<div>loading..</div>)
    // const showitem = this.props.categorylist.
    const categorylist = this.props.categorylist.map((cl, index) => {
      var subcategory = cl.children.map(sc => {
        return <Subcategory key={sc.id} subcatname={sc.categoryname} subcatchild={sc.children} id={sc.id}/>
      })
      return(
        <div>
        <div class="listheader">
        <button key={cl.id} id={"category_" + cl.id} class="category listheaderinner" onClick={this.props.togglesub.bind(this, index)}>
          {cl.categoryname}
            <span class="icon-caret kCaret kCaret-right icon-size-small"></span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div id={"subcategorycontainer-" + cl.id} class="subcategorycontainer container-fluid">
          {subcategory}
        </div>
        </div>
      )
    }, this)

    switch(this.props.view){
      case "mobile":

      return(
        <div class="category-container">
          <BrandContainer />
          <div id="sale" class="listheader">
            <button class="category listheaderinner">SALE<span class="icon-caret kCaret kCaret-right icon-size-small"></span></button>
          </div>
          {categorylist}
        </div>
      )
      break;
    }


  }
}

export default Category
```

and i found a post on SO suggesting that i should breakdown the array into another component so here is my

**subcategory**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class Subcategory extends Component{

  render(){
    console.log('showsub', this.props.showsubcategory);
    var displayquery = this.props.showsubcategory ? "sublistitem listheaderinner ke-btn-transparent" : "sublistitem-hide listheaderinner ke-btn-transparent"
    console.log(displayquery);
      return(
          <div>
          <button key={this.props.id} id={"subcategory_" + this.props.id} class={displayquery}>
            {this.props.subcatname}
              <span class="icon-caret kCaret kCaret-right icon-size-small"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="itemcategorycontainer container-fluid">
          </div>
          </div>
          // <li class="sublistitem categorylistitem" key={sc.id}><Link to="/category">{sc.categoryname}</Link></li>
        )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return{
    showsubcategory: state.interaction.showsubcategory
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Subcategory)
```

I really need help, I've been googling solutions even posted here for days and ended up with nothing

Comment: you end up with nothing because this is too much of code, if you want a rapid answer try to reproduce the issue in JSbin with the minimest code possible.

Comment: Alright thank you for the advice i'll post again with better codes